# Test postgress conneciton to localhost

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm writing a script and want to check if the DB server is up. I've added an alias for my localhost in /etc/hosts and when I ping that, it resolves in my local machine:

```
ping db_host
PING db_host (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <machine name> (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
```

Postgres has an utility to check if the server is ready called pg_isready
Running it on localhost shows the server is up.

```
pg_isready -h localhost
localhost:5432 - accepting connections
```

But running it against the alias hostname fails:

```
pg_isready -h db_host
db_host:5432 - no response
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html) seems to suggest what I'm doing should work, so what gives?

Comment: Your described set up works for me, reporting it to be accepting connections.  What if you try to connect with psql rather than testing with pg_isready?  What if you use the IP address rather than a hostname?

Comment: @jjanes Duh, I had the wrong IP address in /etc/hosts ...